# Use jQuery to set same function for all Select elements in a form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I thought I had this figured out but I must be missing something...

**EDIT:Turns out I WAS missing something very simple... moved the first script to after the  tag and everything worked perfectly!**

I want to clean up my code by setting an onchange handler for ALL the Select elements in a web form. I thought I could use jQuery and do this...

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#myform').on('change', 'select', function() {
            var values = Sijax.getFormValues('#myform') ;
            Sijax.request('func',[values]);
            });
</script>  
</head>
```

but with this form nothing happens...

```
<form id="myform">
  <select name="one" id="one" title="one" >
    <option value="Value_11">Label_11</option>
    <option value="Value_12">Lable_12</option>
  </select>
  <select name="two" id="two" title="two" >
    <option value="Value_21">Label_21</option>
    <option value="Value_22">Lable_22</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

However, when I use the same function inside the select element it works great... What am I missing?

```
<form id="myform">
  <select name="one" id="one" title="one"
    onchange="{ var values = Sijax.getFormValues('#myform') ;
            Sijax.request('func',[values]); }" >
    <option value="Value_11">Label_11</option>
    <option value="Value_12">Lable_12</option>
  </select>
  ...
```

Turns out that I was putting the script in the wrong place! Once I moved it out of the  and put it into the <#myform> element (at the end) it started to work perfectly. I think I SHOULD be able to use an onload handler to do this in the head but haven't got there yet...

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply .on to a container.

So in your case select maybe the body.

```
jQuery('select').on( { change : function() {

            }},"body");
```

Or something like that.

However, the on works on the container and then applies the select on elements within the container.  This means that jQuery doesn't need to traverse the entire page looking for elements to apply events to and speeds the whole thing up.

Comment: I didn't realize that a table was NOT a container :-) Thanks. I'll try it out today and see if I can get it working.